# Invoke AWS lambda function from container without request body

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, container-runtime-interface

I have an AWS lambda function (nodejs) that will return a pdf with Content-Type: "application/pdf".

I learned how to prepare it for deployment in a container image,
and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html) says i can invoke it locally with
`curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'`,
where the -XPOST seems unnecessary as the function will just read the request body provided by --data/-d even if it's from the default -XGET.

Either way, at this point i'm not processing any request body yet, and i could as well not even intend to, but if i omit the request body (or provide an invalid json like `-d "abc"`), the Runtime Interface Client fails before even invoking my function with this error:

```
 {"errorType":"SyntaxError"
 ,"errorMessage":"Unexpected end of JSON input"
 ,"trace":
["SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
,"    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"
,"    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1089:42)"
]}
```

(or `Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0`, for the `-d "abc"`)

If i could access the local function url from browser, i could immediately see the returned pdf result, but there's no way to provide a dummy request body there.
How do I allow the lambda interface to accept simple get requests without a body?

Comment: That's a classic JSON.parse exception in your code, can you share your lambda function code?

Comment: @HimanshuPant my lambda function doesn't parse any JSON, this is returned by the aws-lambda-ric before entering my function. Mind the "file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1089:42" in the stack trace. When I invoke my function directly with nodejs (eg. node -e 'import("lambda.js").then(({handler})=>handler())' ), or provide the -d "{}" body it demands, the response pdf is returned without error.

Comment: Might be worth checking out the index.mjs file and walking through the stack trace.

Comment: @HimanshuPant do you mean I should edit aws-lambda-ric's source code and specify a new ENTRYPOINT in my container calling a `node ./hacked-aws-lambda-ric/bin/index.js $@` script? I did find the place where it parses the JSON in the package, but this doesn't sound very recommendable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

A POST request here doesn't mean your Lambda is required to process a POST request. Because here you're invoking the `aws-lambda-ric`, not the Lambda itself. The runtime interface client is designed in a way to accept a POST request, and then, it invokes your local Lambda.

Inside `-d '{}'` you then provide the exact payload your Lambda is expected to receive as the `event` argument.

If your Lambda designed to work with API GW trigger, and accept only GET requests, then it will look smth like:

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"resource":"/","path":"/","httpMethod":"GET","requestContext":{"resourcePath":"/","httpMethod":"GET","path":"/Prod/"},"headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Host":"70ixmpl4fl.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-5e66d96f-7491f09xmpl79d18acf3d050"},"multiValueHeaders":{"accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"],"accept-encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"]},"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"body":null,"isBase64Encoded":false}'
```

Sample GET request payload for the `event` argument is taken from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html).

So you mock a GET request by modifying what you pass inside `-d '{}'` (see where the example command has `{"resource":"/","path":"/","httpMethod":"GET"`).

Not by changing the HTTP method of `aws-lambda-ric`.

Comment: amazing heureka response, thanks!

Comment: I've marked it as accepted, btw this probably implies that there's simply no way to "visit" the aws-lambda-ric from a common browser. unless this is intentional, it seems like pointless a limitation.

Comment: @bpstrngr yes, this is intentional, and there is no way to "visit" it from browser. If you absolutely need this, you can write a small http server as a  "wrapper"  that will proxy a GET request from your browser to a POST request from aws-lambda-ric

Comment: @VladHolubiev for some reason i have the same error when sending POST request from the browser, even though copying the request from dev tools as CURL and sending it does work - what could be the reason for that ? from what i am seeing here it has something to do with the payload - but again sending the same request as CURL does not cause this problem .